# Upload speed when uploading to google drive with google drive library

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to know my upload speed when I'm uploading a file to google drive.
I used the [Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java) tutorial.

I think this is the area where I need to concern to know my upload speed

```
Insert a file  
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("My document");
body.setDescription("A test document");
body.setMimeType("text/plain");

java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Any idea how am I going to do that?

PS: display the upload speed every 1 sec. So I need to read how many bytes is delivered every 1 sec.

Comment: Time after 'execute' minus time before 'execute' will do. The result will have nothing to do with Google Drive, it will tell you what your network speed is at the moment (and I guess your question will get down-votes soon :-).

Comment: that's exactly my first solution to my teacher but he disagree with me..
i think what he want is to display the upload speed every 1 sec. so i need to read how many bytes is delivered every 1 sec

Comment: Sorry no experience doing that, maybe ['Uploading the file in chunks on  this page'](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads) helps. Or the 'Multipart upload' on the same page.